# Generics - Using parent class to specify type in generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am looking at some covariance/contravariance stuff, I have a much wider question but it all boils down to this:

```
GenericRepository<BaseEntity> repo = new GenericRepository<ProductStyle>(context);
```

This doesn't work, even though BaseEntity is the parent abstract class of ProductStyle, is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: How is *GenericRepository`1* declared?

Comment: I'm guessing the error is something like "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserQuery.GenericRepository<UserQuery.ProductStyle>' to 'UserQuery.GenericRepository<UserQuery.BaseEntity>'"

Comment: I can understand why covariance/contravariance is needed, but why do need what you're trying to do?

Comment: Fundamentally the generics I am using will work as is (I store them in a list cast as object and retrieve using a generic GetRepo method). However, in order to bolt on actions, I need to pass in a specific type, not just an 'object', I'm trying to create a framework so that the logic to be performed upon an object is seperated from the object itself. This will then allow me to overload a particular object by the type passed into it (E.g. EmailAction could be bolted on to a Product, or an Order for when it is saved), so that the action is handled in a different way, depending on the type

Comment: Since `GenericRepository<ProductStyle>` does not have `GenericRepository<BaseEntity>` as a (direct or indirect) base class, the above declaration is illegal. What you need is covariance. But in C# (at least until the current version, 5.0) _only_ generic interfaces and generic delegate types can be made covariant. Not generic classes or generic structs, like you have. So the closest you can get is to make an interface `IGenericRepository<out TEntity>` where the `out` modifier makes the inteface covariant in `TEntity`. Then you can say `IGenericRepository<BaseEntity> repo = ...;` (note the `I`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way of doing that is with an `out` generic restriction (which will make it hard to save objects, but fine to retrieve them), on an **`interface`** (not a `class`). If you have:

```
interface IGenericRepository<out T> {...}
```

then an `IGenericRepository<ProductStyle>` can be assigned to a variable of type `IGenericRepository<BaseEntity>`, since all `ProductStyle` are also `BaseEntity`, and we have restricted ourselves to covariant / `out` usage:

```
IGenericRepository<BaseEntity> tmp = GetRepo<ProductStyle>(context);
// note that the right-hand-side returns IGenericRepository<ProductStyle>
...
private IGenericRepository<T> GetRepo(...) {...}
```

Note, however, that this covariant / `out` usage makes it impossible to do things like:

```
interface IGenericRepository<out T>
{
    T Get(int id); // this is fine, but:
    void Save(T value); // does not compile; this is not covariantly valid
}
```

Comment: You beast! That's exactly the solution I've been trying to find, thanks!

Comment: @DanielDawes just make sure you're aware of the limitations that covariance (or for that matter, contravariance) imposes.

Comment: Have to admit I never used a `<out T>` generic parameter.  Wouldn't have thought of that.  Interesting.

Comment: Using this with Unit of Work pattern so the covariance should be fine, since I'm using the context to manage the save repositories that are generically typed

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering if something like this would also be useful -- using a restriction on the definition of your GenericRepository limiting the base type that `T` can be:

```
void Main()
{
    var repo = new GenericRepository<ProductStyle>(new ProductStyle());
    Console.WriteLine(repo.ToString());  //just output something to make sure it works...
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class GenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity {
    private readonly T _inst;

    public GenericRepository(T inst){
        _inst = inst;
        _inst.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class BaseEntity {
    public Int32 Id {get;set;}

    public virtual void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); }
}

public class ProductStyle : BaseEntity {
}
```

So if you have a `GetRepo<T>` method, that method could return a GenericRepository of T, and you're assured that `T` is a child of `BaseEntity`.